# Setup remote glassfish server on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I'm not a java programmer and don't know much about eclipse or web services.
I needed to create a web service and then set this up on a windows server.
So I set up a localhost Glassfish 3.1.2.2 in eclipse juno ee and created a web service. 
Now its to be transferred to a vm windows 2008 server.

The vm windows 2008 server has been setup with java 1.7 and Glassfish 3.1.2.2.
The glassfish starts up and I can access the admin.

When tried to connect eclipse to this remote glassfish it failed.
New Server
Select glassfish 3.1.2
Server Host name :servername.
Admin Port: 4848
Port :8080
User: admin
ping server 
Cannot connect Hint: run asadmin enable-secure-admin
I have run the asadmin enable-secure-admin but it still gives the same complaint.

`asadmin –host servername –user admin –port 4848 –secure list-applications`

Connects so the glassfish server is there.

`asadmin --host servername --user admin --port 4848 get secure-admin.enable`
`secure-admin.enabled=true`

Command get executed successfully.
So Glassfish is secure.

I can ping the windows server.
I can login to the http//:servername:4848 from my pc. (it does complain about the certificate but still lets me in)

What have I missed?
It doesn't appear to be trying or getting near the server the error appears as soon as the ping is pressed.

If it's something like a firewall how can I test/check this connection?
The hint doesn't help is there an actual error message?

Answer (score 2):

This is really annoying bug, but there is a workaround.

1. Create a localhost glassfish server with default settings. It should appear in the Servers tab.
2. Open server settings and uncheck "Use Anonymous Connection for Admin Commands".
3. Change IP address of a server from localhost to your server address. Now it will connect remotely using admin name and password.